# Global variable and call by reference in Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, variables, servlets, global-variables

I have one Servlet with many Global Variables and many Functions. Every Function needs to read and write to this Variables. The Problem is, that this is not `threadsafe`. When i have the Variables in one Function(doGet\Post), the other cant access them.

Is there a way to to call a Function with a reference instead of a value? 
How do you normally "simulate" global variables?

Comment: why do you need these global variable? Try to avoid such cases.

Comment: Cause i have many functions which will acces the same variables and need the results of the previous function. The functions will always be called in an different order.

Comment: Jean thats the question: how to avoid the global variables in this case?

Comment: If this is in the same servlet, why not making those variables class attibutes ?

Comment: Is data user specific?

Comment: KabulanOlak, the variables are in the Main Servlet class, the only Class in the Servlet. I thought its not threadsafe?

Comment: I don't think ss. Show us some of your servlet (declaration of class and variables)

Comment: OK so i can just Grab the class variable with x=this.x, process it and update the Claes variable with this.x=x and its threadsave?

Comment: Hmm i read in an other topic that the Server just create one instance of a servlet calss, so it woudlnt be threadsafe vor?

Comment: And the variabledata is not userspecific, cant save it in the session...

Comment: Maybe use static Variables? You can synchronize them or put locks on them if necessary

Comment: Cant synchronise cause this would be Bad for the performance. Would be the same like singlethread. I just need own variables for Every request.

Answer (score 0):

In java the calls are always by reference, not by value (unless you serialize with RMI...unlikely).
You could use Thread Local variables to solve this king of issues: have a "global" per thread variable.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Comment: "In java the calls are always by reference, not by value"

You might better want to check your facts, before spreading nonsense.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1

(except for primitive arrays with call-by-reference-ish behaviour)